# Get outgoing sms in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I found a code in StackOverflow that is written for monitoring incoming and outgoing SMS, but this code is written in Java. I want to use it in Xamarin as a Android Service. This is the code:

```cs
public class SMSMonitor
{
    private ServiceController mainActivity;
    private ContentResolver contentResolver = null;
    private Handler smshandler = null;
    private ContentObserver smsObserver = null;
    public string smsNumber;
    public static bool thCountStatus = false;
    public static int thIncreCount = 0;
    public bool monitorStatus = false;
    internal string code;
    public static string activationCode;
    internal int smsCount = 0;

    public SMSMonitor(in ServiceController mainActivity, in Context mainContext)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        contentResolver = mainActivity.ContentResolver();
        smshandler = new SMSHandler(this);
        smsObserver = new SMSObserver(this, smshandler);
    }

    public virtual void startSMSMonitoring()
    {
        try
        {
            monitorStatus = false;
            if (!monitorStatus)
            {
                contentResolver.RegisterContentObserver(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms"), true, smsObserver);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error,"test", "SMSMonitor :: startSMSMonitoring Exception == " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void stopSMSMonitoring()
    {
        try
        {
            monitorStatus = false;
            if (!monitorStatus)
            {
                contentResolver.UnregisterContentObserver(smsObserver);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error,"test", "SMSMonitor :: stopSMSMonitoring Exception == " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    internal class SMSHandler : Handler
    {
        private readonly SMSMonitor outerInstance;

        public SMSHandler(SMSMonitor outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }
    }

    internal class SMSObserver : ContentObserver
    {
        private readonly SMSMonitor outerInstance;

        internal Handler sms_handle = null;
        public SMSObserver(SMSMonitor outerInstance, in Handler smshandle) : base(smshandle)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
            sms_handle = smshandle;
        }

        public virtual void onChange(in bool bSelfChange)
        {
            base.OnChange(bSelfChange);
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    outerInstance.monitorStatus = true;
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    sms_handle.sendMessage(msg);
                    Uri uriSMSURI = new Uri("content://sms");
                    Cursor cur = outerInstance.mainActivity.ContentResolver.query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, "_id");

                    if (cur.Count != outerInstance.smsCount)
                    {
                        outerInstance.smsCount = cur.Count;

                        if (cur != null && cur.Count > 0)
                        {
                            cur.moveToLast();
                            outerInstance.smsNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                            if (string.ReferenceEquals(outerInstance.smsNumber, null) || outerInstance.smsNumber.Length <= 0)
                            {
                                outerInstance.smsNumber = "Unknown";
                            }
                            int type = int.Parse(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type")));
                            string message = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
                            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "test", "SMSMonitor :: SMS type == " + type);
                            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "test", "SMSMonitor :: Message Txt == " + message);
                            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "test", "SMSMonitor :: Phone Number == " + outerInstance.smsNumber);
                            cur.close();
                            if (type == 1)
                            {
                                onSMSReceive(message, outerInstance.smsNumber);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                onSMSSend(message, outerInstance.smsNumber);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //                  Log("KidSafe","SMSMonitor :: onChange Exception == "+ e.getMessage());
                }
            });
            thread.Start();
        }

        internal virtual void onSMSReceive(in string message, in string number)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "test", "In OnSmsReceive");
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "test", "Message" + message);
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "Sample", "Number" + number);
            }
        }

        internal virtual void onSMSSend(in string message, in string number)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "test", "In OnSmsSend");
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "test", "Message" + message);
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Error, "Sample", "Number" + number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problems:

1. How can I access to ContenetResolver in Xamarin , when I convert this code to C# , an error occur about ContentResolver.
2. As the same problem is occurred for Cursor class.
3. In this code (in SMSMonitor class) the ContentResolver is not a part of mainActivity!!!

Comment: where is the C# code you wrote?  "an error occur" is not a useful description of the problem.  What is the specific error message and which line causes it?

Comment: Thanks dear Jason , I got my answer from Leo Zhu’s post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define global static variable for `MainActivity` or pass it as a parameter in `SMSMonitor` constructor.

global static variable:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity Instance;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
         ...
        Instance = this;
       
        
    }

 }
```

then in your SMSMonitor use like:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = MainActivity.Instance.ContentResolver;
```

for Cursor :

```
var cursor =  contentResolver.Query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, "_id");
```

Comment: Thanks dear Leo Zhu